# UIScrollView programmatical scrolling not working iOs 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8

In my application I have a UIScrollView with that has some textfields,  if those textfields are edited they may happen to be placed under the keyboard. I handled this with this line:

```
[_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.origin.x, _scrollView.frame.origin.y, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height - (_keyboardHeight - 44))];
[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_destinationFrame animated:YES];
```

If I break on these statements, everything seems to be in order, the content size is correct, the frame of the scrollview is correct, and the destination frame received is correct, stepping into scrollRectToVisible simply just skips the statement to the next one, and implementing the scrollView delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

and inserting a breakpoint there has no effect, using

```
[_scrollView scrollsToTop];
```

instead has also no effect. So programmatical scrolling seems to have absolutely no effect. This worked perfectly fine before upgrading to the iOs 8 SDK. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: From which method are you calling `scrollRectToVisible:` and/or `scrollsToTop`?

Comment: -(void)keyboardOnScreen:(NSNotification *)notification

it fires in the ViewController when the keyboard is on screen, and it's called from Thread 1 in the application.

Comment: Programmatically scrolling a scroll view does not trigger its delegates. Also scrollsToTop does not scrolls the scroll view to the top, its a boolean to indicate whether it should scroll to top when a user taps on the status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollRectToVisible may not be scrolling because the view may think the "rect" is already visible as the keyboard is animating upwards.

I always handle this by listening to the event `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and then adjusting the `contentOffset` of the scroll view to be the Y origin of the rect with some padding. You may also want to increase the content size at this point to avoid a snapping behaviour when the user tries to scroll the screen when the keyboard is up.

Reverse everything in `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(_scrollView.contentOffset.y + _destinationFrame.origin.y > _keyboardHeight)
    {
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_scrollView.contentOffset.x, _destinationFrame.origin.y - _keyboardHeight )];
    }
```

Instead works perfectly.